# Malloc outside of main() or any other function (i.e. at global scope)

Tags: c++, class, malloc, variable-declaration

I wanted a heap allocated buffer common to a class (to use as a scratchpad during computations).  At some point I may free and then reallocate the buffer if it is not large enough.  I wanted the buffer to exist without having to call a "myclass::initialize();" in main();  I came up with the following code that compiles and works well for my purpose.

My questions are:  Why does this code compile correctly?  Why is malloc() allowed to be outside of main() or any other function?  Is the compiler interpreting this somehow and removing the malloc?

Code compiled on linux 64bit using "g++ example.cpp" and checked with valgrind

```
// example.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

class myclass {
public:
   static char* pbuf;                     // buffer
   static unsigned int length;            // buffer length
   const static unsigned int chunk_size;  // allocation chunck size
};

// set constants and allocate buffer
const unsigned int myclass::chunk_size = sizeof(long unsigned int) * 8; 
unsigned int myclass::length = chunk_size;  // start with smallest chunk
char* myclass::pbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*myclass::length);

int main() {

   // write to buffer (0 to 63 on 64bit machine)
   for (int i = 0; i < myclass::length; i++) {
       *(myclass::pbuf+i) = i;
   }

   // read from buffer (print the numbers 0 to 63)
   for (int i = 0; i < myclass::length; i++) {
     printf("%d\n", *(myclass::pbuf+i));
   }

   free(myclass::pbuf); // last line of program
}
```

Thanks for the answers.  Sound like this is more common than I thought.  "Functions calls are allowed in static initializers". This leads me to a slightly modified version catching a possible malloc error:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

class myclass {
public:
   static char* pbuf;                     // buffer
   static unsigned int length;            // buffer length
   const static unsigned int chunk_size;  // allocation chunck size
   static void* malloc_buf(unsigned int);
};

// set constants and allocate buffer
const unsigned int myclass::chunk_size = sizeof(long unsigned int) * 8; 
unsigned int myclass::length = chunk_size;  // start with smallest chunk
//char* myclass::pbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*myclass::length);
char* myclass::pbuf = (char*)myclass::malloc_buf(sizeof(char)*myclass::length);

void* myclass::malloc_buf(unsigned int N) {
    void* buf = malloc(N);
    if (!buf) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return buf;
} 

int main() {

   // write to buffer (0 to 63 on 64bit machine)
   for (int i = 0; i < myclass::length; i++) {
       *(myclass::pbuf+i) = i;
   }

   // read from buffer (print the numbers 0 to 63)
   for (int i = 0; i < myclass::length; i++) {
     printf("%d\n", *(myclass::pbuf+i));
   }

   free(myclass::pbuf); // last line of program
}
```

Comment: This is an extremely dangerous thing to do. If any other static initializer in a different compilation unit accesses `pbuf`, the results are unpredictable and could vary on different compilers, platforms, and even compilations of the same code with the same compiler. See [static order fiasco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-order-fiasco).

Comment: Congrats on getting four upvotes for your first question. We hope you enjoy your stay at StackOverflow.

Comment: The sample code in main() is misleading (apologies).  In reality the class member functions are the only ones accessing the pbuf data.  I have been calling the buffer a "scratchpad" in my own mind.  The idea is that a member function can use the available scratchpad buffer since it is "available" and "big enough".  If it is too small there is a function to resize it, but it is left "large" as long as needed. The idea being that I just leave the buffer around so that the member functions have a temporary area to use...

Answer (score 2):

It's just doing static initialization (initialization before main is called). Static initializers are allowed to call functions.

Comment: Isn't it precisely dynamic initialization? I mean the pbuf variable initialization. How can the malloc return value be known at compile time?

Comment: I confess that I am unclear on the terminology. It is initializing a `static` variable but I do realize there are multiple ways that happens. It seems like people loosely refer to all of those as "static initialization" since they're initializing static variables but if that's technically correct or not I couldn't say.

Comment: Yes, @JorgeGonzálezLorenzo appears to be correct: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization I do think most people loosely refer to anything that initializes static variables as "static initialization" but I think it is not technically correct here.

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is just another function - which is why it has such specific requirements placed on it to allow it to be called properly.

Other things can and do happen before it gets called.  Static initialization among them.